# Javascript Todo list

Tags: javascript

I want to use the following specifications, but an error occurs - could you tell me how to solve it?

1. Adding tasks (ID numbers are serial numbers 1, 2, 3, 4...)
2. Delete 2
3. ID is displayed as 134
4. Add tasks to ③ (ID is 1, 3, 4, 5...)
5. If you repeat deletion and addition (4, 5, 6, 7, 7...), you will receive an ID instead of a serial number.

> Error code: main.js:71 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property'getElementsByTagName' of null
> at updateId (main.js:71)
> at HTMLButtonElement.delete_element (main.js:65)

```js
    {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const addTaskTrigger = document.getElementsByClassName('addTask-trigger')[0];
    const addTaskTarget = document.getElementsByClassName('addTask-target')[0];
    const addTaskValue = document.getElementsByClassName('addTask-value')[0];
    let nextId = 0;
    const todos = [];

     //Taskとidを作成
    const addTask = (task, id,tableItem) => {    
    let idSpanTd = document.createElement('td');
    let taskSpanTd = document.createElement('td');
      //要素内のHTML文章を変更する
      idSpanTd.innerText = id;
      taskSpanTd.innerText = task;
      //生成したテーブル要素をブラウザに表示する
      tableItem.append(idSpanTd);
      tableItem.append(taskSpanTd);
      addTaskTarget.append(tableItem);
      return(task,id)
    };
    
     //Button要素を生成する
    const addButton = (tableItem, removeButton, createButton) => {
      let createButtonTd = document.createElement('td');
      let removeButtonTd = document.createElement('td');
      //要素内のHTML文章を変更する
      createButton.innerText = '作業中';
      removeButton.innerText = '削除';
      //生成したテーブル要素をブラウザに表示する
      tableItem.append(createButtonTd);
      tableItem.append(removeButtonTd);
      addTaskTarget.append(tableItem);
       //生成したbutton要素を生成する
       createButtonTd.append(createButton);
       removeButtonTd.append(removeButton); 
       return(tableItem, removeButton, createButton);
      };
  
      //追加ボタンをクリックした際にタスクを追加する処理を行う
     addTaskTrigger.addEventListener('click', () => {
       const task = addTaskValue.value;
       const tableItem = document.createElement('tr');
       const removeButton = document.createElement('button');
       const createButton = document.createElement('button');
       addTask(task, nextId++, tableItem);
       addButton(tableItem, removeButton, createButton);
       addTaskValue.value = '';

       removeButton.addEventListener('click', delete_element, false);
  });
    
    //チェックリスト用オブジェクト
    const todo = {
       task: 'taskSpanTd',
       status: '作業中'
    };
    todos.push(todo);
    
    // //削除ボタンを押した時にタスクを削除する
    function delete_element () {
      let tabletag = this.closest ('tr');
      if (tabletag)
      tabletag.remove ();
      updateId();
    }

    //　番号　再振り分け
    let updateId = () => {
      const tbody = document.getElementById("tbody");
      const taskList = tbody.getElementsByTagName('tr');
      nextId = 0;
      Array.from(taskList,tr => {
          nextId++
          tr.getElementsByTagName('td')[0].textContent = nextId;
      });
  }
  
    });
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel ="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <title>Todoリスト</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Todoリスト</h1>
  <p>
    <input type="radio" name="status" value="1" checked="checked">全て
    <input type="radio" name="status" value="2">作業中
    <input type="radio" name="status" value="3">完了
    </p>
<p></p>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>コメント</th>
        <th>状態</th>
        <th></th>
      </thead>
      <tbody class ="addTask-target"></tbody>
    </table>
    <h2>新規タスクの追加</h2>
    <input class="addTask-value" type="text" />
    <button class="addTask-trigger" type="button">追加</button>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
  <!-- <script src="js/dot.js"></script> -->
</body>

</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
const tbody = document.getElementById("tbody");
```

to

```
const tbody = document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
```

since there is no element with id `tbody`. This will fix your null pointer exception. Or even better, give your table an id in case you have multiple `tbody` elements and want to avoid the index access.

Comment: I could swear that when I voted on this post, it didn't have the `[0]`(the array index access).  Of course, I could be too tired.  Either way, I can't reverse the clearly mistaken downvote as it is locked in place until the post is edited, and there is nothing I can do to improve the post to excuse an edit.   That said, I had planned on reversing the vote into an upvote by the time the post was fixed.  But clearly that idea is based on a false understanding.  For the record, I usually don't comment on posts I downvote as usually the owner of the post isn't very receptive.

Comment: @Daedalus Thanks for the feedback. Your are 100% correct that i was missing the `[0]`. I saw it later and fixed it.

Comment: I'm surprised the vote didn't reset the edit grace period then.  I'm sorry, but the vote is locked in place until an edit is made.

Comment: @Daedalus Oh okay, didnt knew about that. Now its edited if you want to change the vote :)

Answer (score 1):

**Problem:**
You have no element with the id "tbody".

So line 70 (`const tbody = document.getElementById("tbody");`) is null. That doesn't cause an error but when you try and find an element within null (`tbody.getElementsByTagName('tr');`), you get an error as tbody is null.

**Solution:**
Add an id to your HTML tbody tags.
Change line 24 of your HTML to  `<tbody id="tbody" class ="addTask-target"></tbody>`. That will fix the error on line 71.